# Detection of closed compound words

Tags: python, part-of-speech

Compound words in English have 3 main types:

```
Open (e.g. ice cream, living room, etc.)
Closed (e.g. snowball, grandmother, etc.)
Hyphenated (e.g. long-term, two-fold, etc.)
```

I am trying to extract `closed` compound words from texts but I don't know how to achieve that. For the `open` compound words I was able to do it with a POS tagger (spaCy):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

sentence = 'I love the icecream'
doc = nlp(sentence)
compounds = [doc[tok.i:tok.head.i + 1].text for tok in doc if tok.dep_ == "compound" and tok.tag_ != 'NNP']
print(compounds) 
# output: ['ice cream']
```

but I can't do the same for the closed ones. How can I detect them in texts?

Is there a list of predefined `closed` compound words?

Comment: Well, can you extract compound words? Can you check if they're hyphenated? If you have a compound word and it isn't hyphenated or open, then by process of elimination it's closed, right? Also, it appears that your example code *detected a closed compound word* and gave you the corresponding open version. Did you just typo the example, or does that perhaps help you solve the problem?

Comment: There is no easy way to detect closed words other than having a predefined list. For example there is no way to know that `father` isn't a compound of `fat` and `her` without a word-list or context.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter said, there's no way to detect these words without a list of them.

Basically the problem is that these compounds are for all purposes the same as ordinary nouns, so in a normal NLP pipeline there's nothing to distinguish them, and for most cases there's no reason to distinguish them either. You also can't work backwards just by looking for subwords, as you'll get false positives like `approach` being `app` and `roach`.

One thing you could do is look for occurrences of open and hyphenated forms of the words. Sometimes the way a word is used is incosistent, and that's a good indicator that it's a compound and not random. For example `hot dog` and `hot-dog` are both relatively common, and could clue in that `hotdog` (which I guess is less common) is a closed compound. You would need a large corpus for this.

Besides that I am not aware of any list of words like this.